# From form submission values - dynamically update CPT "has_archive" slug and custom taxonomy "rewrite" slug value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, forms

I have defined a CPT and corresponding taxonomy like this -

```
function my_custom_post_type()
{
  register_post_type(
    'my_sample_cpt',
    array(
      'public'      => true,
      'has_archive'  => 'store',
    )
  );
  register_taxonomy(
    'collection',
    'my_sample_cpt',
    array(
      'label' => __('Collection'),
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'store'),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_post_type');
```

then I was trying to change both CPT *"has_archive"* slug and custom taxonomy *"rewrite"* slug values dynamically from the form submission values with the code below,

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $store_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['store_name']);
    if (!empty($store_name)) {
        function change_custom_taxonomy_slug_args($taxonomy, $object_type, $args, $store_name)
        {
            if ('collection' == $taxonomy) {
                remove_action(current_action(), __FUNCTION__);
                $args['rewrite'] = array('slug' => $store_name);
                register_taxonomy($taxonomy, $object_type, $args);
            }
        }
        add_action('registered_taxonomy', 'change_custom_taxonomy_slug_args', 10, 4);

        function change_post_types_slug($args, $post_type, $store_name)
        {
            if ('my_sample_cpt' === $post_type) {
                $args['has_archive'] = $store_name;
            }
            return $args;
        }
        add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 3);
    }
}
```

The issue is that none of the two callback functions "*change_custom_taxonomy_slug_args*" and "*change_post_types_slug*" are getting triggered when the form is submitted.

Comment: are you trying to make the archive URLs different based on the user viewing the site? CPT's are registered at runtime in PHP registration doesn't do anything in the database, but if you change rewrite rules/slugs you need to resave and regenerate permalinks, and this will happen for everybody not just the person who filled out the form. I also see that you're trying to use a 3rd parameter on the `register_post_type_args` hook, and you're also trying to use a filter as an action, but that hook does not have a 3rd parameter and that's action is not an opportunity to modify the post type

Comment: Likewise with `registered_taxonomy`, and even if it did work, it would only work on the same request as when the form was submitted because nothing is persisted/saved beyond the current request, so it would immediatley flip back to the default on the next page you viewed. You would need to store it somewhere. **Why do you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this**

Comment: Hi @tom, in a form I am giving the option to the user to set have their own slug('store' by default in this case) so that when the user hits that slug-like wp.com/store it will be like a custom taxonomy archive page and it will list all the custom taxonomy items there. when the user clicks on one of them it will just show the items inside that.
please see these images (https://imgur.com/a/EWZWkNv)

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is, to give the option to users to set up their own slug "shop" instead of "store" or something like that.

Comment: ok, but this will only work on a per site basis, not a per user basis. All users on that site will get the new slug, and you still have to store it somewhere, e.g. in an option, and flush/resave permalinks if that changes

Comment: @TomJNowell  _"this will only work on a per site basis, not a per user basis"_ this scenario is completely fine, I'm giving the slug customisation option for the plugin-installed user, not for the ones who visit their website, also I'm storing the slug in a database, the only issue I'm facing is that none of the two callback functions "change_custom_taxonomy_slug_args" and "change_post_types_slug" are getting triggered when the form is submitted.

Comment: **The approach that you have taken and have asked about is incorrect and _not fixable_.** This is not the solution to your problem. When you make any request for a page to WordPress it is loaded from a blank slate, and when it finishes that slate is wiped clean. This means that even if your filters work, everything they did will only work on the form submission then be forgotten, so it's not possible to fix your filters, and your slug change does not get saved anywhere. You need to save the new slug somewhere yourself, and then use it when you call `register_taxonomy` or `register_post_type`

Comment: this answer on a similar question may be useful to you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/411050/736

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell your answer here( wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/411050/736 ) helped me solved the issue by saving the slug to db and then using that to update the slugs.
Sorry, don't have enough reputation to upvote the anwser.