# How to dynamically register custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, rest-api

I have this code in a custom plugin.

```php
    public function create_new_cpt( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        $args = $request->get_param('newCptDetails');

        $cpt = register_post_type( 
            $args['name'], 
            [
                'label' => $args['label'],
                'description' => $args['desc'],
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true
            ]
        );

        if( $cpt ){
            add_option( 'cpt_name', $args['name'] );
            add_option( 'cpt_label', $args['label'] );
            add_option( 'description', $args['desc'] );
            return $cpt;
        } else {
            return 'not registered';
        }
    }
```

The code is a callback function for a custom REST route that is supposed to get all the needed params to create a new CPT. I've done a test but I've noticed that the CPT is not registered and I think it's because I'm not calling the `init` hook. In my plugin code I'm creating four routes, one is to create new cpt, another to list all cpt and the last two will be used to enable or disable a CPT.

```php
    public function setup_admin_page_routes()
    {

        register_rest_route( 
            $this->namespace, 
            '/list-cpt', 
            [
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => [$this, 'list_cpt'],
                'permissions_callback' => [$this, 'permissions_callback']
            ], 
        );

        register_rest_route( 
            $this->namespace, 
            '/create-cpt', 
            [
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => [$this, 'create_new_cpt'],
                'permissions_callback' => [$this, 'permissions_callback']
            ], 
        );

        register_rest_route( 
            $this->namespace, 
            '/disable-cpt', 
            [
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => [$this, 'deactivate_cpt'],
                'permissions_callback' => [$this, 'permissions_callback']
            ], 
        );

    }
```

How I can call the `init` hook insite my function and how I will enable or disable or delete CPT when from the admin page I'm creating the user will give the related command?

Comment: why do you want to register post types via a REST API route?

Answer (score 1):

*That's not how post type and taxonomy registration work, **they are already dynamic**. You must call `register_post_type` on every request, no exceptions, and **never** later than the `init` hook. If you do not do this, then the CPT doesn't exist.*

`register_post_type` and `register_taxonomy` store their data in PHP variables, and do not save that data anywhere, so once the request ends that information disappears and needs to be re-registered on the next request. So it doesn't make sense to modify a CPT's definition the way you describe.

It also can't be called later than the `init` hook. This means it is not possible to register a custom post type in an form/AJAX/REST API handler, that is too late and also won't be passed on to the next request because of the way registration works.

**Instead, you can receive new values the same way you would any other form or AJAX, save them in the database as options or another way. Then on the `init` hook, before you call `register_post_type`/`register_taxonomy`, grab those values you saved earlier and use them in the arguments.**

---

Remember PHP applications aren't like Node.js sites, they don't have long-running background tasks that wait for requests. Instead they're loaded fresh from the disk, generate a response, then they end. All variables dissapear at the end of the request, and the next request starts from a blank slate.

Additionally, if you try to change the URL or anything that's used in the URL, then you need to flush and resave permalinks.

Comment: noting that the options system won't scale beyond a single CPT, so you probably want an internal CPT that just stores all this information, then on `init` loop through them activating them. This is exactly what the custom post types plugin does alrady. Ironically setting `show_in_rest` to trye on such a CPT would give you exactly what you were trying to build for free

Comment: ok, so i need to use `add_option()` for each new CPT I want to create, and grab the info later right?The main problem is, if there isn't any CPT when the plugin is installed, what I will set into the `register_post_type` ?

Comment: not sure if it can be a good way to achive what I want to do, but probably I can pass an array to `add_option()` with all the info about the new desired CPT. Then in the `init` that I will place in a custom method of the plugin, call the `get_option()` and loop for all the CPT and register it? Can you show an example that can help me please?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can have multiple options with the same name like `add_option('registered_cpt', array(...) )`

Comment: you just need to store that information somewhere, then retrieve it when you call `register_post_type` on the `init` hook. How you do that is entirely up to you, and yes you're right you can't have multiple options with the same name. Note that it seems you're reinventing the wheel and there's already a very popular plugin for registering post types with a UI. You also don't have to use options to store your data, how you store it is entirely up to you. I also notice that you never provided any context for why, theres a very high chance there's a better way than dynamic CPT's for what you want

Comment: I've read about that plugin. I'm trying to improve my wp develop skills, but this plugin I want to make is for a company site where I will need to manage different CPT with different vue front end and a single back end. I want to give to the team mates that will manage the wp contents the ability to add CPT based on their needings, the company won't use external plugins if isn't necessary andI want to avoid having in the menù CPT that aren't useful in a certain moment

Comment: Probably the best solution is to save the cpt info in a dedicated wp db table and get the info to pass to the init every time

Comment: dynamically registering CPT's isn't the only way to limit things that way, there are custom taxonomies too, menus can be hidden via role, and queries can be filtered. You can also use a custom post type rather than a custom table to store CPT data. Generally writing SQL in WP without needing to interact with 3rd party software that have tables is an anti-pattern